# How do I disable the tooltip message for the input type=date field?

Tags: html, date, input, tooltip

I want to hide the default tooltip message that says "Show date pikcer" when I hover the cursor over the calendar icon while using input type="date"
here is my code,
Birthday:

I tried adding title attribute to the input field but it didn't work.
Birthday:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip you are seeing is the default behavior of the browser for the input with **type="date"**. Unfortunately, it's not straightforward to remove or hide this tooltip because it is browser-controlled, and its appearance and behavior are not easily customizable.

To make it customize, you can use a different approach. One common method is to use a JavaScript library for date picking, such as **react-datepicker** if you are using React. These libraries often provide a more customizable across different browsers.

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
```

Comment: I am not using any library, simple html5

Comment: Here is the code <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">